# Hide Empty Fields

Tags: php, field

I'm trying to hide the empty fields in the following:

```
<?php 

$events = get_group('Gallery');
foreach($events as $event){  ?>

<a href="<?php echo $event['gallery_image_1'][1]['o']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo     $event['gallery_image_1'][1]['t']; ?>" /></a>
<a href="<?php echo $event['gallery_image_2'][1]['o']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $event['gallery_image_2'][1]['t']; ?>" /></a>
<a href="<?php echo $event['gallery_image_3'][1]['o']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $event['gallery_image_3'][1]['t']; ?>" /></a>

<?php }?>
```

At the moment all fields display whether or not there is actually an image there. I've tried numerous solutions but no luck so any help would be much appreciated

many thanks

Comment: You mean not output *empty* event images?

Comment: So images with an empty src attribute?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if (array_key_exists('gallery_image_1', $event) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $event['gallery_image_1'][1]['o']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo     $event['gallery_image_1'][1]['t']; ?>" /></a>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

echo the who link instead of just the url and path. That way, you can choose not to display the link if there is no image.

```
if (!empty($event['gallery_image_1'][1]['t'])) {
    echo "<a href=\"" . $event['gallery_image_1'][1]['o'] . "\"><img src=\"" . $event['gallery_image_1'][1]['t'] . "\" /></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful but I'm unsure as your question was very broad:

```
<?php 

$events = get_group('Gallery');
foreach($events as $event){ 

  for($i=1;$i<4;$i++) {
    if(empty($event['gallery_image_'.$i])) 
      continue
      ;
    $image = $event['gallery_image_'.$i];
?>

<a href="<?php echo $image[1]['o']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[1]['t']; ?>" /></a>

<?php } }?>
```